# При запуске ubuntu появляется черный экран и курсор вместо lxde

Tags: linux, lxde

Решил на ubuntu становить lxde, для работы с графическими библиотеками. После установки, перезапустил компьютер и на экране появляется черный экран и курсор мыши, дальше оболочка не грузиться в чем проблема?

Comment: нет нажимаю правой ничего не происходит

Comment: спасибо сделал похожим образом только через lxdm помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была аналогичная проблема в `CentOS 7.6` с `gdm 3.28` после авторизации в `X`. Похоже, что это глюк `gdm`.

1. Открываем вторую консоль: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Запускаем `htop`, находим `X` процесс и посылаем ему `SIGTERM`.

   - <kbd>F4</kbd> набираем `gdm` - чтобы найти `X` процесс
   - <kbd>F9</kbd> ⇒ `SIGTERM`
3. `X Window` перезапустится и со второй попытки `gdm` будет работать нормально.
4. Для входа в систему без авторизации можно добавить в `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

   ```
    AutomaticLogin=username
    AutomaticLoginEnable=True
   ```

---

Дополнительно:

- `gdm` для `gnome`.
- `lightdm` для `xfce`.
- `lxdm` для `lxde`.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Полезно, пригодилось. (+1) Решал подобную проблему так же.